# is there a way to do custom Window not time based on Kafka stream, using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Kafka stream sending me data of heartbeat for cyclist on circuit.
I need to able to do AVG of heartbeat for each lap he did. I tried to use the session but it only works on time and in my case the time could be different each lap.

I found with foreachBatch I can create a Window on any column.

```py
.foreachBatch(calculate_heartbeat)
```

and in this function:

```py
def calculate_heartbeat(df, batch_id):
    lap_window = Window.partitionBy("lap")
    df = df.withColumn("avg", avg("heartbeat").over(lap_window))
    df.show(truncate=False)
    df.groupBy("lap").agg(avg("heartbeat")).show()

    return df
```

but when using the `foreachBatch` I a not able to accumulate the whole data of the lap, is there a way to do it ?

I tried different approach to create and empty dataframe and add each batch I received to it
I am expecting to get accumulate the whole lap in the dataframe, or any better approach to do my calculation ? or windows the lap

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use `session_window`? It works along with the groupby function on any identifier such as your `lap` field.

Comment: I assume since you are receiving a stream of events that you have an event timestamp of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Spark 3.4.0 for this test.

I have generated some CSVs in /content/input directory with the following content which I understand will be present in your event stream:

```
lapId,heartbeat,timestamp
1,122,2023-05-23 10:01:00
1,132,2023-05-23 10:02:00
2,137,2023-05-23 10:03:00
2,122,2023-05-23 10:04:00
2,132,2023-05-23 10:05:00
3,137,2023-05-23 10:06:00
3,122,2023-05-23 10:07:00
3,132,2023-05-23 10:08:00
4,137,2023-05-23 10:09:00
```

Using the session window aggregation functionality of Spark Structured Streaming where in this case it is assumed that one event will be reported at least every 5 minutes (otherwise the lap is considered as over)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, TimestampType,StringType,LongType
from pyspark.sql.functions import session_window, avg

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
  StructField('lapId', StringType(), True),
  StructField('heartbeat', LongType(), True),
  StructField('timestamp', TimestampType(), True)
])

df = spark.readStream.format("csv").schema(schema).option("header",True).load("/content/input")

# This is the part that interests you
avg_heartbeat_rate_per_lap = df \
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes") \
    .groupBy(
        session_window(df.timestamp, "5 minutes"),
        df.lapId) \
    .agg(avg("heartbeat"))

query = avg_heartbeat_rate_per_lap \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .queryName("aggregates") \
    .format("memory") \
    .start()

spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show(truncate=False)
```

The results are correct as per the inputs:

```
+------------------------------------------+-----+------------------+
|session_window                            |lapId|avg(heartbeat)    |
+------------------------------------------+-----+------------------+
|{2023-05-23 10:06:00, 2023-05-23 10:13:00}|3    |130.33333333333334|
|{2023-05-23 10:01:00, 2023-05-23 10:07:00}|1    |127.0             |
|{2023-05-23 10:09:00, 2023-05-23 10:14:00}|4    |137.0             |
|{2023-05-23 10:03:00, 2023-05-23 10:10:00}|2    |130.33333333333334|
+------------------------------------------+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know we can use the session windows in this way. I thought we can only use it when we have an empty gap between 2 sessions.

Comment: is there a way on stream to use the avg calculated value to filter data from the main stream ?  df = df.where(df["heartbeat"] > avg_heartbeat_rate_per_lap.tail(1)["avg(heartbeat)"]) this did not work, but something similar

Comment: You should open a new question and reference this one to get additional help